# Construct Balanced BST consisting sum of each node and its children The output should be the postOrder traversal of the new binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

Example:

Sample Input:

6

6 10 20 1 51 43

1 10 6 20 43 51

Sample Output:

20 6 51 131 94 36

Sample Input:

5

40 60 30 20 50

50 20 30 60 40

Sample Output:

100 40 200 150 130

In the input, the first value 6 is the size of the tree. The values in the second line correspond to the inorder traversal of the given binary tree, and the last line corresponds to the pre-order traversal of the given binary tree.

The output is the post-order traversal of the new binary search tree that is supposed to be constructed with node values separated by spaces.

Below is my code but output is not coming properly .

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
class Node
{
    int value;
    Node leftchild, rightchild;

    Node(int item)
    {
        value = item;
        leftchild = rightchild = null;
    }
}

class BinaryTree
{
    Node root;
    static int preIndex = 0;
    static int index=0;

    Node constructTree(int in[], int pre[], int inStrt, int inEnd)
    {
        if (inStrt > inEnd)
            return null;

        Node tNode = new Node(pre[preIndex++]);

        if (inStrt == inEnd)
            return tNode;

        int inIndex = search(in, inStrt, inEnd, tNode.value);

        tNode.leftchild = constructTree(in, pre, inStrt, inIndex - 1);
        tNode.rightchild = constructTree(in, pre, inIndex + 1, inEnd);


        return tNode;
    }

    int search(int arr[], int strt, int end, int value)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = strt; i <= end; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == value)
                return i;
        }
        return i;
    }

    int sumBinaryTree(Node node)
    {
        // Write the logic to recursively create Binary Tree consisting of sum of all its children
        if (node == null)
            return 0;

        // Store the old value
       int old_val = node.value;


        // Recursively call for left and right subtrees and store the sum
        // as new value of this node
       node.value = sumBinaryTree(node.leftchild) + sumBinaryTree(node.rightchild);



        // Return the sum of values of nodes in left and right subtrees
        // and old_value of this node
       return node.value + old_val;


    }

    void printPostorder(Node node)
    {
        if (node == null)
            return;

        // first recur on left subtree
        printPostorder(node.leftchild);

        // then recur on right subtree
        printPostorder(node.rightchild);

        // now deal with the node
        System.out.print(node.value + " ");
    }

    void inOrder(Node node, int array[])
    {
        if (node == null)
            return;
        inOrder(node.leftchild, array);
        array[index++] = node.value;
        inOrder(node.rightchild, array);

    }

    Node ArrayToBST(int arr[], int start, int end) {
        // Write logic to convert the array representing Binary Tree to Binary Search Tree
        if (start > end) {
            return null;
        }

        /* Get the middle element and make it root */
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        Node node = new Node(arr[mid]);

        /* Recursively construct the left subtree and make it
         left child of root */
        node.leftchild = ArrayToBST(arr, start, mid - 1);

        /* Recursively construct the right subtree and make it
         right child of root */
        node.rightchild = ArrayToBST(arr, mid + 1, end);

        return node;
    }
}
class Source{

    // driver program to test above functions
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int len = scanner.nextInt();
        int in[] = new int[len];
        int pre[] = new int[len];
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
            in[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
            pre[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();
        Node root = tree.constructTree(in, pre, 0, len - 1);

        tree.sumBinaryTree(root);
        int inSumTree[] = new int[len];
        for(int i=0;i<=inSumTree.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(inSumTree[i]);
        }

        tree.inOrder(root, inSumTree);
        Arrays.sort(inSumTree);
        Node bstRoot = tree.ArrayToBST(inSumTree, 0, len-1);
        tree.printPostorder(bstRoot);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

node.value += sumBinaryTree(node.leftchild) + sumBinaryTree(node.rightchild);

You are missing that + sign, thats it!! Also there's no need to put an extra variable for old_val. Just return node.value..

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for `sumBinaryTree(Node node)` and it should work.

```
int sumBinaryTree(Node2 node)
    {
       
        if(node==null)
            return 0;

        node.value += sumBinaryTree(node.leftchild) + 
                      sumBinaryTree(node.rightchild);

        return node.value ;

    }
```